# Integrator key review is getting failed, due to api limit not reching 20 days per day

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign sandbox environment, and want to move `Integrator Key` to live production, but after submitting To review, it getting failed every time.

I have done many api calls via my end system to docusign, which is using that Integrator Key. Not sure why its happening.
Can someone help me to get , where I can see my api limits of Integrator key. and how to make Review successful.

I am talking about below step.

[image]

Comment: Have you changed the sandbox url to production url?? if not can  you please paste the response you got.

Comment: Its not about api call. I am making Integrator key live to Production, for that I have to pass the `Review`, that is getting failed. It is saying you should call atleast 20 api calls. I am doing also, but not able to cross check no of api calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to https://demo.docusign.net/ and enable API Request logging. Instructions [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging).

Also checkout this DocuSign blog [post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/checking-api-logs-like-the-weather/) to troubleshoot issues with your API calls.